# Can I setState inside function passed to useCallback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This question occurred to me because as we know from the docs:

> useCallback(fn, deps) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, deps).

The docs of `useMemo` say:

> Remember that the function passed to useMemo runs during rendering.
> Don’t do anything there that you wouldn’t normally do while rendering.
> For example, side effects belong in useEffect, not useMemo.

I assume that also implies I can't do `setState`.

Now, if we have this code:

```
const res = useMemo(() => fn, []);
```

Does above quote mean we can't do a side effect inside `fn`, or the inline function which was the argument to `useMemo`?

Because if it means we can't do side effect inside `fn` it means we can't do a side effect also in a function passed to `useCallback` because that line is same as:

```
const res = useCallback(fn, []);
```

Comment: I suspect you're not the only one to be confused by that part of the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see how you got there, but it's a slight misreading of the docs. (Fairly easy mistake to make.)

The function that the `useMemo` docs are talking about isn't your function (`fn`), it's this function in the `useCallback` "equivalent `useMemo`" example:

```
useMemo(() => fn, deps).
//      ^^^^^^^^
```

That function doesn't call any state setters, so it's fine.

It's absolutely fine and completely normal to call state setters in callback functions you memoize via `useCallack`. *(As long as you don't call your callback during rendering.)* When you do, be sure to either:

- Not use any state variables in when calling the state setter:

  ```
  const fn = useCallback(() => {
       setSomething(someValueNotFromState);
  }, []);
  ```

  or
- Use the callback form of the state setter:

  ```
  const fn = useCallback(() => {
       setSomething(something => something + 1);
  }, []);
  ```

  or
- Declare any state members you're going to use in the callback as dependencies:

  ```
  const fn = useCallback(() => {
       setSomething(something + 1); // I usually avoid this
  }, [something]);
  //  ^^^^^^^^^
  ```

A more verbose example/comparison:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

const changeHandler1 = useCallback((event) => {
    // Absolutely fine to call `setValue` here
    setValue(event.currentTarget.value);
}, []);

// equivalent to:

const changeHandler2 = useMemo(() => {
    // NOT okay to call `setValue` here (the function we pass to `useMemo`)

    return (event) => {
        // Absolutely fine to call `setValue` here
        setValue(event.currentTarget.value);
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with this "Memoize the callback with any state members you're going to use with the state setter"? You mean to pass the right dependencies?

Comment: @giorgimoniava *"so the docs are referring to "() => computeExpensiveValue()"?"* Yes, exactly! *"You mean to pass the right dependencies?"*  Yes. That would be a less confusing way to put it. :-D I've edited that in, and given examples of all three of those things for clarity.